# Progress Bar Issue VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, progress-bar, webbrowser-control

having a slight issue when loading the progress bar for my Web Browser, whenever I input the code, it is having issues with the Windows.Forms.WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs part in my program, for some reason, its acting like it is written incorrect and tried to figure out what exactly is wrong here.

```
Private Sub Loading(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Windows.Forms.WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs)
    ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = e.MaximumProgress
    ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = e.MaximumProgress
End Sub

Private Sub Done(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).DocumentTitle
    ComboBox1.Text = CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Url.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: An obvious mistake setting the value property.  It is not generally useful anymore, modern web pages are made from *many* downloads, 30 is not unusual.  This feature dates back to the previous century and dial-up modems.  Today your broadband Internet connection and large browser cache will just make it flicker madly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `value` to the `maximum` every time so this won't display correctly.

**But** - You shouldn't use the `MaxiumProgress` to set the `Maximum` value of the progress bar because `MaximumProgress` is a `Long` and the ProgressBar `Value` is an `Integer`, so it could overflow if you have a large document.

What you should do is to calculate the *percentage* progress and display that:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.ProgressChanged
    Dim percentage As Integer
    'calculate the percentage checking for zero maximum as an error case
    If e.MaximumProgress = 0 Then
        percentage = 0
    Else
        percentage = CInt(e.CurrentProgress / e.MaximumProgress * 100)
    End If
    'make sure it is in bounds of the progress bar
    If percentage >= 0 AndAlso percentage <= ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        'set the value
        ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = percentage
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigated(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigated
    'set the value to zero when we have finished
    ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = 0
End Sub
```

Now you can just set the progressbar minimum to 0 and the maximum to 100 (which are the default values)